# Python re words and numbers only

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&` and some other characters, and also remove tabs, new lines, and multiple spaces. I just want to clean up and have words and numbers.

As an example:

```
test! should be test
<script> should be script
test   test should be test test.
```

I tried using `re.sub('[/.!,;+()]#-&?=<>|%$', ' ', string);`. This replaced some of them but as I added more characters to replace it stopped working. Suggestions?

Comment: `re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', "testing!   moth$er"))` should take care of everything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you placed the new characters outside of the character class box.

Try this.

```
re.sub('[/.!,;+()#&?=<>|%$-]', ' ', string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some, if not all those characters you are using are special regex characters, and the regex engine is interpreting them as literal characters.

A better way of doing what you're asking is to remove all characters that AREN'T in the set of characters you want.

```
re.sub(r'[^0-9A-Za-Z \.]', '', input)
```

Removing multiple spaces is a little more complicated.

```
re.sub(r'\s{2,}', '', input)
```

Remove any whitespace two or more times with nothing.